# How to make a single roll scroll on overflow over multiple grid row

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I wrote some linea of HTML/CSS code that span four books images in a row, the overflow is enabled to auto when the screen becomes responsive. The challenge is how to make just a single row scroll at a time but other rows keep scrolling alongside when it overflows.
Below is my code snippet

```css
.book-section-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 3rem;
  grid-row-gap: 5.5rem;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.book-section-grid>div img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-section-grid">
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/220x312/b3d7ff/FFFFFF/?text=Book-A" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/220x312/4169E2/FFFFFF/?text=Book-B" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/220x312/c4c4c4/FFFFFF/?text=Book-C" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/220x312/17a2b8/FFFFFF/?text=Book-D" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/220x312/b3d7ff/FFFFFF/?text=Book-A" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/220x312/4169E2/FFFFFF/?text=Book-B" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/220x312/c4c4c4/FFFFFF/?text=Book-C" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/220x312/17a2b8/FFFFFF/?text=Book-D" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can I make use of JavaScript in this case?

Comment: You can do that if you create 2 container divs (.book-section-grid). Any reason you want the horizontal scrolling?

Comment: I thought about that but I'm going to dynamically generate data into that tag using Angular ngFor but first, it must be arranged here and my dynamic wouldn't keep creating divs on it own

Comment: Your question is pretty confusing, you said your goal is to only have one row, but "not all the rows scroll at a time when it overflows." What do you mean "all the rows?" You just said you only wanted one.

Comment: I just edited the question, I guess it should be clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned angular you could use an array in an array. This way you have control and have as many horizontal scrollable divs as you want. Since you will be working in rows you would be better of using flexbox instead of a grid. But I will ignore that in my code.

**stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-38myfi

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  data = [ ['Photographer #1', 'Photographer #2', 'Photographer #3', 'Photographer #4'], ['Photographer #5', 'Photographer #6']];
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="book-section-grid" *ngFor='let array of data;'>
  <div *ngFor='let item of array'>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/220x312/b3d7ff/FFFFFF/?text=Book-A" alt="">
    <h4>{{item}}</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
.book-section-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 3rem;
  grid-row-gap: 5.5rem;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.book-section-grid>div img {
  width: 100%;
}
```